# Set Text of cell different than value in Infragistics

Tags: winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Is it possible to set value to Infragistics UlraGridCell and have different value on text. 
If I try use

```
myCell.Text = "test";
```

It's seams to be read only and when I try to use:

```
checkProjectCell.SetText
```

I'm getting an error.

I would like to have a long value in value field and string as a text field.
Do you have an idea how I can handle this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show some text to the users and to store some long value you need to implement IEditorDataFilter interface. Look at this article in Infragistics documentation showing how you can achieve this "[Using the IEditorDataFilter Interface with WinGrid](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/wingrid-using-the-ieditordatafilter-interface-with-wingrid)"